# How do I make Facebook style profile URLS?

Tags: php, facebook, url, styles, social-networking

I am making a small social network and was wondering how can I make facebook style profile urls. For example:

**My current url styling:** www.website.com/user.php?id=username

**Facebook style url that I want:** www.website.com/username

I was wondering if this can be created with php? It would be easier to remember.

Comment: Which web server are you using? This is cannot be controlled by PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([^\.]+)$ profile.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Would let you goto example.com/profile/username?1=1&2=2&3=3, ect

Resources:

www.htaccess-guide.com/

www.htaccessbasics.com/

www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess.shtml

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess

Answer (score 0):

You open the .htaccess file and modify the contents:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess.shtml